# Login redirects to login page instead of login

Tags: login

For a few days, the login and register in our shop do not work. A login will be directly redirected to the login page instead of logging in the user.

- Form_key is set.
- The action of the login form is HTTPS.
- The login page is `https://xxxx.com/de/customer/account/login/`
- I have checked the config in :

> System > Configuration > Customer > Customer configuration > Login
>   options

- The value for "re-direct to account dashboard" was YES. A switch to "NO" had no effect.

What could be a possible reason? This is our shop: https://www.serverandstorage-shop.de

Comment: Its a debugging task, can you confirm if the data is being posted to controller customer/account/LoginPost (vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost)? I would suggest you to check line by line code by printing required values and ensure if it breaks at any point..

Comment: Please specify your Magento version?

Comment: I made a test register on you account , and it redirected me to account dashboard .  Not sure what is your issue .

Comment: Currently, It's Working or not? I just check it's working.